# Cómo fijo el máximo sobre el que actúa el gráfico

Tags: java, android, android-studio, charts, mpandroidchart

He creado un gráfico de dónut con MPAndroidChart.
Necesito establecer manualmente un máximo para que el gráfico en vez de ser sobre 100 sea sobre 15, que es la suma de las dos entradas

```
 ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    entries.add(new PieEntry(5, "Entrada 1"));
    entries.add(new PieEntry(10, "Entrada 2"));
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "");

    dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
    dataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    dataSet.setValueTextSize(12f);
    PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    binding.chart.setData(data);
    binding.chart.animateY(1000, Easing.EaseInOutCubic);
    binding.chart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    binding.chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    binding.chart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    binding.chart.setHoleRadius(35f);
    binding.chart.setTransparentCircleRadius(40f);
    binding.chart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.WHITE);
    binding.chart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12f);
    binding.chart.invalidate();
```

[image: Dos entradas que equivalen a 5 y a 10, pero el gráfico es sobre 100]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambiando `binding.chart.setUsePercentValues(true);`
a false: `binding.chart.setUsePercentValues(false);`

Comment: Hola Roxas2402, bienvenido, no me queda claro si esto es una respuesta a tu propia pregunta o un anexo, si es anexo, deberías editar tu pregunta, agregarlo allí, y eliminar esta no-respuesta, en caso contrario,deberías aclarar en que forma esto resuelve tu problema, las respuesta que son solo código, están consideradas de baja calidad, evita recibir votos negativos.